# how to fix index matrix

Tags: python, matrix

hello every one I have created this function, it calculates Gc per step (pas) and puts results in a matrix , but the problem is that is puts everything of the index 0 of the matrix, how can Ib fix this? I want to put each value to have an index (first value on 0 , second on 1 ....ect)

def gc_content_mat(sequence , pas):   #pas = step

```
num_fen=len(sequence)/pas   #num_fen = windows number
values = np.zeros(num_fen)

#print values
#print n                   
for i in range(0,num_fen):
    values [i]  =gc_content(sequence[i*pas:(i+1)*pas])  #function gc_content is already defined

return np.matrix(values)
```

I appreciate you help

Answer (score 0):

Which value is in `pas` ?
You should ensure that `num_fen` is an integer with the good numbers.